# Sequelize: How to exclude fields from being updated by `upsert` method

Tags: sequelize.js

**Situation**

- I am using Sequelize's (v5.8.9) `upsert` method to insert/update records 
  in a table with unique index.
- I am using Postgres 11, and each table has the fields `createdAt`, `createdBy`, `updatedAt` and `updatedBy`.

**Problem**

When I upsert a record in a table, Sequelize generates SQL like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.sequelize_upsert
(OUT created boolean, OUT primary_key text)  AS $func$ 
BEGIN INSERT INTO "table1" ("name","created_by","updated_by","created_at","updated_at") 
VALUES (...) RETURNING "id" INTO primary_key; created := true; 
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN 
UPDATE "table1" SET ...,"created_by"='user1',"updated_by"='user1',"updated_at"='2019-07-03 23:45:05.872 +00:00' 
WHERE ("id" IS NULL OR "name" = '...') 
RETURNING "tag_id" INTO primary_key; created := false; 
END; $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 
SELECT * FROM pg_temp.sequelize_upsert();
```

As we can see Sequelize is updating the created_by field when the record already exists (unique_violation).

I cannot find an solution or workaround so that the created_by can be excluded from the update. I also like to stick to `upsert` as it is more efficient than checking the existence by select and then do insert or update. Any suggestion is appreciated.

I understand I can specify the `fields` parameter, but as per the [doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert):

`The fields to insert / update. Defaults to all changed fields`

But in my case I do need to insert the `created_by` field if the insert of upsert succeeds.

I am also thinking raising a feature request in Sequelize so that in the model definition I can register a list of fields which should be excluded from all updates (instance save, Model.update, upsert, etc), not just `createdAt`.

Answer (score 0):

In the upsert method you can pass an object as second parameter with **fields** key to provide the list of fields to insert or update.

Check this doc:

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert

```
db.model.upsert({
  ...yourData
},{
  fields: [...NameOfFieldsToBeUpdated]
}).then(function(test){})
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and sorry I didn't make myself clear. The `fields` applies to both create and update. In my case I do need to insert into `created_by` if the upsert is a insert.

Answer (score 0):

The `bulkCreate` method has a parameter called `updateOnDuplicate` which accepts an array of fields to update when a conflict is identified.

```js
const register = {name: "foo", createdBy: "someId"};

Model.bulkCreate([register], {updateOnDuplicate: ["name"]});
```

In this case, the insert will include all of the fields (`name` and `createdBy`), although the update will only include the field `name`.